# get all indexes declared in database from java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Is there any standard java api that returns the indexes declared in the database. I tried using the getIndexInfo() in database meta data but that seems to expect a table name as input and does not meet my requirements.
Thx.

Comment: Why? If knowing the indexes makes some difference to how your Java application executes there is something seriously wrong.

Comment: we are cloning tables in our application and as part of that we are cloning the constraints and indexes too - so i'll have to generate unique index names. hashing etc wont work due to restrictions on length of names in some db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes are declared on tables. So you should first retrieve all tables with DatabaseMetaData.getTables() and then loop over the table names to get all indexes.

Comment: understood the logical concept but it looks like an inefficient way to do it. since i'll be making too many db hits.

Comment: How many tables do you have ? Normally this is not a performance problem.

Comment: This is very cheap. Only opening the connection is the most expensive step. You can just do this all in the same transaction. A good alternative is to use a connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to fire off some sql which will vary depending on the DBMS you are using.

For example DB2 would be:-

```
select * from sysibm.sysindexes where tbcreator = 'IMPACT';
```

For sqlite it would be:-

```
Select * from sqlite_master where type = 'index';
```

Comment: i was hoping there would be std api to do this. looks like i have to fire a sql to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% portable "query" way of doing this, however many DBs do implement the standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA, so you can queries like this.

```
    sql = "select TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, NON_UNIQUE, COLUMN_NAME " +
            "from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS " +
            "where TABLE_SCHEMA = ? " +
            "order by TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX";
```

MySQL and SQLServer support this.  Oracle does not.

See [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)

EDIT:  I originally said "no 100% portable way", however you can use the JDBC metadata APIs which will achieve this, however as noted in a previous answer this may be inefficient depending on the number of tables.